# JSON to JSON Converting: Flattening

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I get from

```
data1 = [
    { "label": "Some Label", "value": '018'},
    { "label": "Another Label", "value": '020'}
]
```

to

```
data2 = {
    "018": "Some Label",
    "020": "Another Label"
}
```

how should the for loop look like?

```
for (let item of data){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with the `for..of` loop, you can do:

```
var data2 = {};

for (let item of data) {
  data2[item.value] = item.label
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object.

```js
var data = [
 { "label": "Some Label", "value": '018'},
 { "label": "Another Label", "value": '020'}
] 

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.value] = e.label;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: is it cross-browser-compatible ?

Comment: You can see `Browser compatibility` on mdn

Comment: Why use `reduce` over `map`?

Comment: `map` is used to get a new array from an old array. `reduce` is used to reduce an array to a single value, which in this case is an object so I would say it's a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and build an object with values as key.

```js
var data1 = [{ label: "Some Label", value: '018'}, { label: "Another Label", value: '020'}],
    data2 = {};

data1.forEach(function (a) {
    data2[a.value] = a.label;
});

console.log(data2);
```

Comment: is it cross-browser-compatible ?

Comment: it is actually [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) by any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
var data1 = [{
  "label": "Some Label",
  "value": '018'
}, {
  "label": "Another Label",
  "value": '020'
}];
var data2 = {};
for (i = 0; i <= data1.length - 1; i++) {
  data2[data1[i].value] = data1[i].label;
}
console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work fine

```js
/** declare data1 */
const data1 = [
  {
    label: 'Some Label',
    value: '018'
  }, 
  {
    label: 'Another Label',
    value: '020'
  }
]

/** declare data2 */
const data2 = {}
    
/** loop data1 to get data2 value */
data1.forEach(item => {
  data2[item.value] = item.label
})

console.log(data2)
```